# Is the song "World In My Eyes" ever mentioned in Ready Player One?

Tags: ready-player-one

*World In My Eyes*, released by Depeche Mode in 1990 as part of their album *Violator*, is the song in the trailer for *Ready Player One (2018)*. Given that Ready Player One (the book) is a veritable love letter to the 1980s, this seems an interesting choice for the trailer. So I was wondering if the song (or artist, or album) was mentioned somewhere in the book, or if the decision to use it was entirely unrelated.

Comment: In terms of cultural trends, a "decade" doesn't instantly stop at 11:59 PM, 12/31/XXX9. I'm not actually familiar with the song in question, and it's been a while since I read the book, but a song from 1990 can absolutely be thematically appropriate for "the 80's" despite the technicality of not being released in the 80's.

Comment: To amplify what @Walt said, the focus of Halliday's obsession was the things he grew up with *in the 80s*.  There are 70s references and a sprinkling of 90s references in the book, which is consistent with someone who grew up in the 80s.  For example, Rush's 2112 dates back to 1976.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**No**

The albums / songs / bands mentioned in the book are:

"Every single one of [Monty Python's] albums"

Dead Man's Party - Oingo Boingo

Everywhere at Once: A Million Miles Away - Plimsouls (1983)

Hysteria: Pour Some Sugar on Me - Def Leppard (1987)

"Beds are Burning" - Midnight Oil  (1987)

"every single Rush album, bootleg, and music video ever" - specifically - 2112: Rush

"Star Wars" original soundtrack - John Williams

"Conan the Barbarian" soundtrack - Basil Pouledouris

"Also Sprach Zarathustra" - Strauss

"Three is a Magic Number" - Bob Dorough (1973)

Get to Know You Well" by Howard Jones

"Blue Monday" by New Order

"Union of the Snake" by Duran Duran

"Rebel Yell" by Billy Idol

"Time After Time" by Cyndi Lauper

"James Brown Is Dead" by L.A. Style

"Atomic" by Blondie

"Wake Me Up Before You Go-Go" by Wham!

"Change" by John Waite from the Vision Quest soundtrack

"Don't Let's Start" by They Might Be Giants

"Dirty Deeds Done Dirt Cheap" - AC/DC

"In Your Eyes" by Peter Gabriel

"Kids Wanna Rock" by Bryan Adams

The Police

Journey

The Clash

Devo

Bill Hicks

Van Halen

Bon Jovi

Pink Floyd

Falco

Pat Benetar (Planet named Benetar)

Dokken

Frank Zappa (Joe's Garage is the name of a Zappa album)

Pac Man Fever

Schoolhouse Rock - Various songs

R.E.M.

Comment: Save you some trouble - https://www.shmoop.com/ready-player-one/allusions.html

Comment: Went ahead and made it community since you've commented some items I didn't find - feel free to plug them in @JohnP

Comment: I think that's about it...

Comment: awesome @JohnP - and if movie adapation form holds - not a single one of those will be in the film LOL

Comment: I'm surprised Depeche Mode didn't get mentioned. Very few of the New Wave musicians got included. Also no David Bowie :(

Comment: Also as an aside, I anticipate a resurgence in "Guitar Hero: Warriors of Rock" sales, as you can play the entire 2112 album on Rock Band/Guitar Hero. (Which is insanely difficult to do well, btw)